# Keep track on keyboard key's state (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, events, keyboard

I would like to keep track of the keydown and keyup events of all the keys on the entire keyboard. My idea was to create a class that stores their keycodes as properties. As seen below --

```js
function Keyboard(){
  var self = this; // Store this object instance for the events
  this.key = {};
  
  // Events
  window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    self.key["k"+e.keyCode] = true;
  });
  window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
    self.key["k"+e.keyCode] = false;
  });
}

Keyboard.prototype.active = function(keyCode){
  if(this.key["k"+keyCode] === true){
    return true;
  }
  else{
    return false;
  }
}


/* Testing below */
var keyboard = new Keyboard();
setInterval(function(){
  console.log("Space(keycode = 32) active: " + keyboard.active(32));
},1000 / 4);
```

This is working, quite well actually. But it seems really inefficient to store them in an object like this. Is there any alternatives and what are your thought on this?

Comment: That's exactly how I'd approach it too.  Do you have any reason for questioning the efficiency?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Since you can't press the same key twice at the same time, I would just push all the keyCodes to an array on keydown and use indexOf() and splice() to remove it again on keyup.

Comment: @Archer I'm developing a game, meaning I can't have anything inefficient running or it will start to lag. As for the questioning, that's where I don't want to trust myself since my computer science knowledge is very limited.

Comment: I don't see an issue with it.  Don't look for performance issues unless you have a reason to.